# macOS Mail.app insists on using wrong IMAP server for iCloud mail account, how to change?

Tags: icloud, mail.app

Mail.app on macOS Big Sur somehow got the mail server settings for my iCloud mail account wrong (see screenshot) and these settings cannot be edited for iCloud accounts. I don't really know how the Gmail IMAP server got there in the first place. I tried disabling and then re-enabling iCloud mail in the system preferences (**System Preferences** > **Internet Accounts** > **iCloud** > **Mail**) to no avail. On my other devices, there is no problem using this iCloud mail account.

Is there any way to correct this without wiping the machine? I tried to look for a .plist file containing these settings so I could edit them manually, but I could not find any.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why wouldn't you just remove the iCloud account and then re-add it?  Why would you need to wipe the entire machine?

Comment: I tried, but it's not trivial. First, the sign out button is greyed out and not clickable, second I fear that by logging out I could lose data (iCloud Drive, Photos etc) or take a long time to re-sync with possible sync conflicts in the process. So I'd rather just edit the server settings somehow if that makes sense.



  Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcJxU.png

Comment: Try Preferences in Mail and see if you can change the Server Settings for iCloud.

Comment: If you are afraid of losing data, worry more about the backups you aren't making than about the email account.

Comment: I appreciate your concern about my backups. My data is backed up of course. Still, I'd rather not risk 1.5 TB worth of possible sync issues and the time and labour associated. I merely seek a way to edit the wrong IMAP settings if that makes sense, this settings have to be stored somewhere, right? @Gilby Sadly for iCloud mail accounts these settings are not editable in the Preferences in Mail

Comment: Where's that image from? I can't find that specific sheet. Outgoing Mail settings should still be in the same place in Big Sur they always were… Mail > Prefs > Accounts > [click account] > Server settings. There's a drop menu to select outgoing server, or set up a new one - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBaNw.jpg

Comment: Ah, OK - then you're just looking in the wrong place...

Comment: @Tetsujin This sheet is found in the Mailbox list on the left > iCloud Mailbox (right click) > Get Account Info > Summary. I included this sheet for explanatory reasons, because only here you can see both the incoming and outgoing server settings.

Your described method sadly does not work, b/c for iCloud accounts, you cannot edit the incoming mail server (now wrongly imap.gmail.com) at all – there just is no text field at all!

The outgoing is already set to iCloud (but this contains the wrong smtp.gmail.com settings, which I seek to change but can't).

Comment: Delete the gmail server, see what happens

Comment: @Tetsujin I already deleted all other mail accounts, save for the iCloud account in question (which is not deletable trivially, as staded above)

Comment: So guys, please, let us keep this real. The mail server settings for iCloud accounts cannot be changed in the interface (I really would like to invite you to try for yourselves and prove me wrong if you doubt me in this regard). So, with all respect and appreciation for your help, could we please stop talking about my backups and my looking in the wrong place :-) What I'm really seeking is your guys' insight where to change these non-editable settings in a .plist, because they *have* to be stored in the file system somewhere, right? Thank you so much!

Comment: I didn't say to delete any accounts. The server list is completely separate to the accounts list. Anyway, I'm done.

Comment: There is no gmail server in the server list.

Comment: OK, then I simply don't know. Wish you luck.